# android studio project migrating to gradle build system warning

Tags: android

i have just migrated to ubundu 64bit 14.04 LTS operating system...after downloading android studio, i picked the option "Check out project from Version Control" to pull a project from github repository. In the next step after cloning the project i checked the "Create project from existing sources" option, after that i followed all the steps without changing anything and the project loaded in Android Studio. The problem is that i get "Migrate Project to Gradle?
This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system." warning and i get the following error logs[image]:

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to import the project rather than simply opening the project?
File->New->Import project.